Ordering in dynamodb with limit
Currently I have a dynamodb (of which I cant anymore change the way the data is structured) which has a partition and sortKey but both are pretty much used as the composite primary key of the data (like you have with relational databases). Here an example of the structure:
partitionKey sortKey     sendMessageTime
id-1         target-1  
id-1         target-2
id-1         message-1/1 dateTime
id-1         message-1/2 dateTime

In here you can see that id would be the same for all the different sortKeys and only the sortKeys are a bit different but not really sortable (the id's in the DB are UUID). Is there a way to make it sortable on sendMessageTime (which is only present with the message-* sortKey) or is my only option to handle this in code? Wanted to limit the amount of message-1/* records I retrieve from dynamodb.

There are a number of ways you can address this, but it may mean adding an additional attribute to your items to index on.
Have a read of this blog post which outlines what your asking:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-data-sorting-with-amazon-dynamodb/#:~:text=The%20sort%20key%2C%20also%20known,values%20of%20the%20sort%20key.
